# The difference between const auto& vs as_const?

Tags: c++, c++17

Basically, I'm trying to learn about C++ 17, and I found `as_const`.

What's the difference when we use:

```cpp
MyType t;
auto& p = as_const(t);
```

instead of:

```cpp
MyType t;
const auto& p = t;
```

Are there some advantages here?

Comment: What is `t`? Is it a function call or expression, or a named variable, or something returning a reference?

Comment: @alterigel sorry for confusing, the `t` is a variable just like `MyType t;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case they are the same.

`std::as_const` is usually used to select the const version from a set of overloaded (member) functions. The following is an example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Notes).

```
struct cow_string { /* ... */ }; // a copy-on-write string
cow_string str = /* ... */;
 
// for(auto x : str) { /* ... */ } // may cause deep copy
 
for(auto x : std::as_const(str)) { /* ... */ }
```

Even if you use `for(const auto &x : str)`, a deep copy may still happen.

Comment: How would a deep copy happen on `const auto&`? Nothing is copied at all.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Because `str.begin()` is called, which will copy the string in usual COW implementations.

Comment: "select the const version from member functions", could you explain this? if I have two member functions like `int get(void) { /* ... */ }` and `int get(void) const { /* ... */ }`, `as_const` will call the second version of `get` if I use `auto &val = as_const(t.get())`?

Comment: @Mer The correct call is `as_const(t).get()`.

Comment: @xskxzr No, it won't be copied because `str.begin()` would return a const iterator which cannot be used to write the buffer.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Such implementation will usually provide two `begin`s, one for non-const objects (which returns non-const iterator and triggers copy) and one for const objects. If you don't use `as_const`, the non-const `begin` will be called.

Comment: @xskxzr Oh, yes, you're absolutely right. I had a senior moment, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple case of assigning to a reference, I doubt either option has any objective benefit over the other. Personally I prefer seeing the `const` attached to the variable but that's entirely subjective.

`as_const()` has one important benefit: it can be used to force `const`ness without requiring a variable declaration. E.g., when calling a method where the `const`ness of the parameter matters:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void example(int const & i) {
  ::std::cout << "const int" << ::std::endl;
}

void example(int & i) {
  ::std::cout << "int" << ::std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int i = 5;

  example(i);                    // Prints "int"
  example(::std::as_const(i));   // Prints "const int"
}
```